Slight Issue With Kanban Board (Items Jumping) - DnD Kit - Sandbox Available
I've successfully created a Kanban Board with Dnd Kit - but I've got a little issue. The issue resides with the onDragOver function I believe.
The Kanban Board currently has 3 functionalities:

Moving a column between other columns
Moving a task inside its own column.
Moving a task between other columns.

The Issue
When I move either a column or task in one direction, in either of the aforementioned use cases, there doesn't seem to be much an issue, it seems to function okay.
However, when I move a column or task in one direction, then try and move it back without lifting my finger of the mouse, it intially jumps 2 instead of moving back incrementally. It only jumps when you move backwards after going forwards.
This issue does not occur when moving tasks between columns.
Potential Cause
This is the array move function I import from @dnd-kit/sortable, im wondering if it's fit to handle moving backwards after forwards?
export function arrayMove<T>(array: T[], from: number, to: number): T[] {
  const newArray = array.slice();
  newArray.splice(
    to < 0 ? newArray.length + to : to,
    0,
    newArray.splice(from, 1)[0]
  );

  return newArray;
}

I have re-created the bug in a sandbox environment for ease of viewing and fixing.
I'll be honest, my handleDragOver function is a bit of a mess, I feel some of the logic inside is redundant and it's bloated, but i'm pretty sure thats the cause of the issue.
There's no fluff in the sandbox anyway, so you should be able to see whats going on.
Here is the code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/kanban-3wq44f?file=%2Fapp%2Fpage.jsx
Thanks alot in advance! This issue has been bugging me for a couple of weeks now. If someone could rewrite the handleDragOver function to be lean and optimized and work without the bug I would be eternally grateful. Its for my SaaS launching a in a couple of weeks and one of the few remaining issues im trying to fix!
